# Open Source Graph Layout Library

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, graph-layout, graph-algorithm

I'm looking for an open source (GPL, LGPL etc) graph layout library for .net framework, preferably fully managed code. Im not worried about the visualisation aspect of things.

I can find lots of them for Java, but none for .net...

Thanks!

Comment: A very useful and on-topic question, thank you. I mean who can get opinionated about a graph layout library?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/589900/24874.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/ (Nice "visualisation aspect of things" :)
(...and for the "oldie" GraphViz, you can get no less than [3 language bindings for C#](http://www.graphviz.org/Resources.php))

Comment: Found this referenced in the duplicate link, look poplar with over 5000 downloads so will give it a try - thanks!

Comment: @James: GraphViz I bet has way more downloads (it's been around since ages) - though it might not qualify as fully managed. :)

Comment: Yeah the fully managed part is really important, and it needs to be a library

Answer (score 2):

http://satsumagraph.sourceforge.net

Has force-directed graph layout (charged particles & springs model).

Answer (score 1):

http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page

Tried it before...works great.

Comment: Looks more like a charts library unfortunately